# select directories exclusively and move to a new folder

Tags: bash

I want to move directories within the current dir to a new folder

```
ls -al
drwxr-xr-x  16 me  staff   512 Jul  8 10:00 .
drwx------+ 16 me  staff   512 Jul  8 05:38 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff  6148 Jul  8 04:56 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 me  staff     0 Jul  7 18:26 .md
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    67 Jul  7 09:36 Actions.md
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff    96 Jul  8 04:56 Books
lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff    41 Jul  7 09:41 Coder -> /Users/me/Desktop/Django/Coder
drwxr-xr-x   5 me  staff   160 Jul  8 07:05 Git
drwxr-xr-x   8 me  staff   256 Jul  8 06:32 Linux
drwxr-xr-x   3 me  staff    96 Jul  7 11:11 Python
drwxr-xr-x  10 me  staff   320 Jul  8 05:42 SQL
drwxr-xr-x   7 me  staff   224 Jul  8 10:00 django
drwxr-xr-x   4 me  staff   128 Jul  7 18:45 error_log
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff  1543 Jul  8 08:38 log_details.md
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff   700 Jul  8 05:00 log_summary.md
-rw-r--r--@  1 me  staff    61 Jul  8 04:56 readme.md
```

I tried the code:

```
#retrieve all the files and dirs
files_and_dirs=(${echo *})
#loop the array and select dirs
for fd in ${files_and_dirs[i]};
    if [[ -d "$fd"]];
        mv -r "$fd" dst_dir
```

However, encounter error in the first step

```
$ files_and_dirs=( $(echo *))
$ files_and_dirs
-bash: files_and_dirs: command not found
```

Comment: This is not the code you ran. I know this because you pasted it twice, and it is different in each case. And because the 2nd example **does not** produce the error that you say it does. Please paste the code that you are having trouble with. Don't make it up from memory, or we end up debugging your transcription errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select directories with the glob:

```
for d in ./*/; do
  mv "$d" dest_dir/
done
```

If you *did* want to use an array + an explicit test

```
files_and_dirs=( ./* )
for fd in "${files_and_dirs[@]}"; do
  if [[ -d "$fd" ]]; then
    mv "$fd" dest_dir/
  fi
done
```

AFAIK unlike `cp`, `mv` doesn't take a `-r` (recursive) option.

`files_and_dirs` is not found because it isn't a command - if you want to see the *values* in the array, use `echo "${files_and_dirs[@]}"`

Comment: `mv ./*/ dest_dir/` would work too unless there's too many arguments..

Answer (score 0):

```
files_and_dirs="$(echo *)"
```

No spaces around the `=`

And please paste you code that you are working on, not a poor copy. This answer is based on the error message. As the code does not produce an error message, but does have some problems (lack of quotes, and un-needed parenthesis).